# ubuntu 12.04 Boot stuck at splash screen

Tags: boot, login-screen, plymouth

I tried to change lightdm with gdm but when I set the computer to use gdm and logged out lightdm was used, so I uninstalled gdm, now this is the problem:

I shut down my computer and went to sleep, at the other day, I turned my pc on and it got stuck at splash screen. I tried to start from recovery mode but did not work also I see this error: sbd asking for cache data failed and keeps going and going to no end (I left the computer at this for about 30 minutes and it did not start) I tried reinstalling gdm from recovery mode and setting lightdm before uninstalling but nothing seems to work.

I have been forced to use windows again and is very under-productive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed It the problem was that I removed gdm without configuring it to lightdm so in recovery mode I reinstalled gdm and was able to startup and change it back to lightdm

Comment: do not forget to accept this solution :)